# Store less than 100 user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to store 100 user information in MongDB.
In fact, the information would be just a boolean, like `{["user1":{"allow":true},"user2":{"allow":false}]}`

I have two choices:

1. Store all users in one json in one 'row'
2. Create a user collection and store users in separate rows, like relational DB.

What is the preferred way for it?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stackoverflow.

It's your application call, of how to structure your documents. I'd create users collection and add documents, as it gives me flexibility to add new users later, and updating same document multiple times give me no benefit.

However, it highly depends on your application logic on how to structure your documents.

Comment: I know this depends on application logic. I thought I had given enough details. The logic is simple, application would read all users' configuration for display and may choose to change some users' configuration for editing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proper JSON

```
[{
        "user": "user1",
        "allow": true
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "allow": false
    },
    {
        "user": "user3",
        "allow": false
    },
    {
        "user": "user4",
        "allow": true
    }
]
```